# How to increase the selection area of a fabric Object?

Tags: fabricjs

Consider the following code:

```
var lineObj = new fabric.Line([120,200,320,200],{
  stroke: '#000000',
  strokeWidth: 1
});
canvas.add(lineObj);
```

This 1 pixel line is very hard to select owing to its very small width.
What I wish to do here is to increase its selection area.
Like this:

[image: Line Corners]

Is there any way in which I can accomplish this?

Comment: I don't see any way of using the API to increase the size of the line's hittest bounding box.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, we have `padding` value for that.

```
var lineObj = new fabric.Line([120,200,320,200], {
  stroke: '#000000',
  strokeWidth: 1,
  padding: 20
});
canvas.add(lineObj);
```

[image]

Did I mention Fabric is flexible and powerful? :)

@markE Nice solution! Glad you're finding it easy to walk through source code.

Comment: Absolutely Perfect! This is exactly what I needed. Thanx again @kangax.

Comment: Flexible and powerful... yes. Easy to find the functionality you need... not always. I've been working on this problem for an hour, trying to manually adjust the bounding box, etc. Padding? I wouldn't have thought of it. Glad to have finally found this answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Bad news--no solution in API / Good news--you *can* code your solution**

The API doesn't provide a way to expand the boundingbox of a line, so there's no API way to get a bigger selection area for lines.

FabricJS is open-source and well-organized and the source code itself has useful comments. Here's what I found...

"Line" objects extend the "Object" object.  The "Object" has helper methods and the most pertinent is in the file object_geometry.mixin.js.  In there, I found that the boundingbox for any object is being generated using the method getBoundingRect().

**You did ask "Is there ANY way...", so here's that way:**

So to solve your issue, you must over-ride the getBoundingRect() for lines and make it slightly wider.  This will automatically make the selection area of your lines wider and more easily clicked.  @Kangax, feel free to indicate any simpler solution!

To get you started, here is the source for getBoundingRect() from the source file object_geometry.mixin.js:

```
getBoundingRect: function() {
  this.oCoords || this.setCoords();

  var xCoords = [this.oCoords.tl.x, this.oCoords.tr.x, this.oCoords.br.x, this.oCoords.bl.x];
  var minX = fabric.util.array.min(xCoords);
  var maxX = fabric.util.array.max(xCoords);
  var width = Math.abs(minX - maxX);

  var yCoords = [this.oCoords.tl.y, this.oCoords.tr.y, this.oCoords.br.y, this.oCoords.bl.y];
  var minY = fabric.util.array.min(yCoords);
  var maxY = fabric.util.array.max(yCoords);
  var height = Math.abs(minY - maxY);

  return {
    left: minX,
    top: minY,
    width: width,
    height: height
  };
},

/**
 * Returns width of an object
 * @method getWidth
 * @return {Number} width value
 */
getWidth: function() {
  return this.width * this.scaleX;
},

/**
 * Returns height of an object
 * @method getHeight
 * @return {Number} height value
 */
getHeight: function() {
  return this.height * this.scaleY;
},

/**
 * Makes sure the scale is valid and modifies it if necessary
 * @private
 * @method _constrainScale
 * @param {Number} value
 * @return {Number}
 */
_constrainScale: function(value) {
  if (Math.abs(value) < this.minScaleLimit) {
    if (value < 0)
      return -this.minScaleLimit;
    else
      return this.minScaleLimit;
  }

  return value;
}
```

Comment: I too had made changes in the fabric.js file, however, this was affecting the flexibility and the ease of enabling/disabling this feature. Thanx all the same @markE.